# How to get Row Value & Sum/ Aggregate in Same row? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, select, aggregate

Just wondering if I have data like

```
 name  score
    A    2
    B    5
    C    7
```

I would like to have a 3rd row

```
     name  score  total
        A    2     14
        B    5     14
        C    7     14
```

I mean ultimately -- I want to find 'z-scores' or percentiles of various row entries across various totals. I'm just not sure if there's a simple way to compare row values to aggregate values, except by a subquery such as

```
select A.name, A.score, B.total
from myTable A
left join
(select name, sum(score) from myTable group by name) B
on A.name = B.name
```

That could work but it seems inefficient querying the same table twice for what is a calculation. Is there any simpler way of doing it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. It's called "window aggregate functions":

```
select
    A.name, A.score, 
    sum(A.score) over () as total
from myTable A ;
```

The `OVER ()` means that the aggregate (sum in this case) is over the whole result set. If you wanted the total over say different names (assuming you had rows with same `name`, you could use `OVER (PARTITION BY name)`.

Comment: Thanks -- yes I used rank()over (partition by) all the time -- of course rank isn't really an aggregation but perhaps it somewhat is as it's group-looking. But this is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Yeah. I suppose "window functions" is a better name for ROW_NUMBER / RANK / DENSE_RANK functions.